# check size of C type at build time

Tags: c, waf

I want to establish build-time cross-language ABI compatibility with Waf. How would I go about checking the size of a type (or any arbitrary type-like checks), and recording it into the build configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a program which outputs that size. I saw this apporach on several `./configure` files:

```
cat << EOF > test.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    printf("int %d\n", sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
EOF
$(CC) test.c -o out
./out >> sizes
rm -f test.c out
```

Of course, with testing of erroneous cases and such.

**Edit**: See the [waf](http://waf.googlecode.com/svn/docs/apidocs/tools/c_config.html) documentation. Specially, read the `run_c_code` method. For saving the value of `sizeof` you can write to a file instead and read it from Python/Waf. Or, see the `define_ret` argument.

Comment: Great - how do I communicate this in Waf? Like, how would I go about catching the output if I used `waflib.Tools.c_config.validate_c()`?

Comment: HURR DURR I'm dumb. It's right there in the documentation. The 'define_ret' argument. Add it to the answer and I'll totally accept it.

Comment: Actually, it's soooo much easier in Waf to just save it to the context's env var. That said... *well you can see*